# Bitmap not getting from 9 patch image Drawable , Also want its Height-width

Tags: android, android-drawable

i have create Bitmap from `Drawable` `recieve_btn.9` patch image

```
BitmapDrawable mimage =(BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.recieve_btn);
```

Error log like

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

also want to get height - width like

```
  int mheight  = mimage.getBitmap().getHeight();
  int mwidht = mimage.getBitmap().getWidth();
```

but issue is cant create `Bitmap` from 9 patch `image`.

Comment: AFAIK 9 patch images are meant for layout or views' background only, why are you using it as a bitmap object?

Comment: want to get it Height

Comment: Are you setting it as a background to certain view, and trying to get its height afterwards?